# Can I use emacs on my computer to compile C code via ssh to a linux terminal?

Tags: linux, emacs, ssh, terminal, putty

So I just started a computer science course and we are learning C. Well, we are supposed to know it already. They suggested that we use emacs to write our C code.

So what I do is use putty to ssh into one of the linux computers in the lab. I am wondering if i can download emacs onto my laptop instead of using the one in the terminal. So i have a session open on one of the computers in the lab from my laptop but i am using a program on my laptop to compile the code. Hopefully that makes sense.

I am wondering if this is possible or do i have to use the emacs within the terminal (the one that's not color coded and looks nice.)

Comment: you can but it will be a hack you'll spend hours trying to get to work.  You want to enable font-lock-mode:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EnablingFontLock

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79100/how-to-open-a-remote-file-ssh-with-my-local-emacs This would help for sure.

Thanks & Regards,   
Alok

Comment: If for whatever reason you must do it on Windows, use Emacs from Cygwin instead of the one you can download from GNU site. Cygwin version will work with the SSH client provided by Cygwin (tested and confirmed by many users), but getting Emacs to work with Putty may be a major headache, and might not work at all in the end. Normally you'd use the terminal version of Emacs with Cygwin, but if you really want the GUI version you could install X-server from Cygwin (but that may be a bit complicated).

Comment: @wvxvw I don't find Cygwin/X to be at all complicated to install from cygwin setup. That said, there is also the cygwin emacs-w32 package which I have not tried but it is supposed to be a Cygwin emacs with Win32 GUI.

Comment: @aap I remember having some problems with it trying to install Octave (it needs X-server for plotting data), but I really don't remember what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand all your requirements, but all the following can be done:

- Install Emacs on your machine; install a C compiler on your machine; and do all your work locally.
- Do all the work remotely in putty (as you've been doing, apparently).
- Install Emacs locally, to edit and compile remote files (i.e. the files stay on the GNU/Linux server and are compiled there, but you edit them in your local Emacs, via Tramp which internally accesses them via ssh).

You can install precompiled binaries for the above, or you can compile them yourself.

Even better, you can install GNU/Linux on your machine, so that installing Emacs or a C compiler is then a simple matter of "aptitude install gcc emacs".